# Is it possible to create empty object from class is extends BaseModel?

Tags: java, android

I have a database of type dbflow i created Organization class contains columns but I want to create from this class a new object is empty with no data So that it can store new data , I designed everything but I get the same data with each new object , Can I actually do that ?, What can I do to do this task ?

```
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Database;
@Database(name = MyDatabase.NAME, version = MyDatabase.VERSION)
public class MyDatabase {
    public static final String NAME = "MyDataBase";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
}

import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Column;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.PrimaryKey;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Table;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.BaseModel;

@Table(database = MyDatabase.class)
public class Organization extends BaseModel {
    @Column
    @PrimaryKey
    int id;

    @Column
    String name;

    private Organization organization;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(){
        super();
    }

    public Person(String name, String lastName){
        this.name=name;
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(){
        super();
    }

    public Person(String name, String lastName){
        this.name=name;
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```